# How to check that the code/test-coverage of cobertura.xml files is above a specified threshold?

Tags: c#, powershell, code-coverage, xunit, cobertura

I have a .Net 5 solution with multiple projects and multiple test projects. I want to make sure either **everything** or a specified percentage value (e.g. 80%) got covered by tests. I'm using xUnit for my tests and created the following Powershell script based on the docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage?tabs=windows#generate-reports

```sh
dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage";

reportgenerator -reports:'**/coverage.cobertura.xml' -targetdir:'CoverageReports' -reporttypes:'Cobertura';

[XML]$report = Get-Content CoverageReports/Cobertura.xml

if($report.coverage.'line-rate' -ge 20)
{
    Write-Host "greater or equal than 20"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "less than 20"
}

Read-Host -Prompt 'done'
```

which does the following

- it runs the tests and creates one *cobertura* file per test project
- it merges every *cobertura* file into one and puts it into the *CoverageReports* directory
- it parses the .xml file

now I have access to the coverage info, e.g. the line-rate. Instead of the dummy if statement, how can I achieve the following sample?

```sh
if($report.coverage.percentage -lt 80)
{
    Write-Host "Coverage is less than 80 percent"
}
```

and as a bonus I could write down a list of things that are not covered yet.

---

This is the content of a generated Cobertura.xml file from a dummy project

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE coverage SYSTEM "http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/xml/coverage-04.dtd">
<coverage line-rate="1" branch-rate="1" lines-covered="4" lines-valid="4" branches-covered="0" branches-valid="0" complexity="4" version="0" timestamp="1627911309">
  <sources>
    <source>C:\</source>
  </sources>
  <packages>
    <package name="ClassLibrary1" line-rate="1" branch-rate="1" complexity="3">
      <classes>
        <class name="ClassLibrary1.BoolReturner" filename="C:\...\ClassLibrary1\BoolReturner.cs" line-rate="1" branch-rate="1" complexity="3">
          <methods>
            <method name="Get" signature="(...)" line-rate="1" branch-rate="1" complexity="1">
              <lines>
                <line number="5" hits="3" branch="false" />
              </lines>
            </method>
            <method name="GetFalse" signature="()" line-rate="1" branch-rate="1" complexity="1">
              <lines>
                <line number="6" hits="1" branch="false" />
              </lines>
            </method>
            <method name="X" signature="()" line-rate="1" branch-rate="1" complexity="1">
              <lines>
                <line number="7" hits="1" branch="false" />
              </lines>
            </method>
          </methods>
          <lines>
            <line number="5" hits="3" branch="false" />
            <line number="6" hits="1" branch="false" />
            <line number="7" hits="1" branch="false" />
          </lines>
        </class>
      </classes>
    </package>
    <package name="ClassLibrary2" line-rate="1" branch-rate="1" complexity="1">
      <classes>
        <class name="ClassLibrary2.StringCombiner" filename="C:\...\StringCombiner.cs" line-rate="1" branch-rate="1" complexity="1">
          <methods>
            <method name="Combine" signature="(...)" line-rate="1" branch-rate="1" complexity="1">
              <lines>
                <line number="7" hits="2" branch="false" />
              </lines>
            </method>
          </methods>
          <lines>
            <line number="7" hits="2" branch="false" />
          </lines>
        </class>
      </classes>
    </package>
  </packages>
</coverage>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cobertura report provides line coverage information as 'line-rate' attribute. It contains value in range from 0 to 1 (1 means 100%). Attribute 'line-rate' is defined at different levels: for entire report - `coverage` root element; for particular assembly - `package` element; for particular class - `class` element and etc.

If the goal is to check code coverage percentage for the entire report (the entire code base), this can be achieved with the flowing code snippet

```sh
[XML]$report = Get-Content CoverageReports/Cobertura.xml

if ($report.coverage.'line-rate' -lt 0.8) {
  Write-Host "Coverage is less than 80 percent"
}
```

---

If the code coverage percentage should be checked more selectively, for example at the class level, then code snippet could be as follows

```sh
[XML]$report = Get-Content CoverageReports/Cobertura.xml

# Select all rows with line-rate < 0.8 (80%).
$classes = $report.SelectNodes('//class[@line-rate < 0.8]');

# Check number of selected rows.
if ($classes.Count -gt 0) {
  Write-Host "Coverage is less than 80 percent"

  #Write list of files with low coverage.
  $classes | Sort-Object -Property 'line-rate' | Format-Table -Property 'line-rate', filename
}
```

In this example the list of classes with the low coverage is selected using [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression `//class[@line-rate < 0.8]`. It selects all `class` elements with `line-rate` attribute value lesser than 0.8 (80%).

---

Also, instead of XPath, similar logic can be written directly in PS code when more complex data analysis is required, for example

```sh
[XML]$report = Get-Content CoverageReports/Cobertura.xml

$classes = $report.SelectNodes('//class');
$lowCoverage = $false;

foreach($class in $classes){

  # Convert line-rate value to 0..100% range.
  $percentage = [int](100.0 * [double]$class.'line-rate');

  if ($percentage -lt 80) {
    Write-Host $class.filename " [$percentage%]"
    $lowCoverage = $true;
  }
}

if ($lowCoverage) {
  Write-Host "Coverage is less than 80 percent"
}
```

Advanced XML processing techniques can be found in answers to
[ForEach in XML file with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48507273/foreach-in-xml-file-with-powershell) question.

Comment: Welcome @Botan! Very nice answer.